# How to use Django template variables in template tags

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I've defined a custom tag function and am trying to pass two arguments into the function that are derived from the array I'm looping through.

Essentially, I'm trying to do something akin to the following:

```
{% for x in array %}
  {% custom_tag_function {{ forloop.counter }} {{ array|length }} %}
{% endfor %}
```

However I'm receiving a parsing error as django is passing in the argument as a string (e.g. `"{{ forloop.counter }}"`) instead of the evaluated value.

I tried to do this:

```
{% for x in array %}
  {% with cnt={{ forloop.counter }} len={{ array|length }} %}
    {% custom_tag_function cnt len %}
{% endfor %}
```

But I receive the same parsing error.

Is there a proper way to do this within django?

Comment: In your second attempt, you have forgot to write {% endwith %}.

Comment: Have you checked this?
{% custom_tag_function forloop.counter array|length %}

Comment: That worked, thanks Mehdi!

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Mehdi in his comment above, the following solves the problem:

```
{% for x in array %}
  {% custom_tag_function forloop.counter array|length %}
{% endfor %}
```